# How to set StopWatch count multiple times in C#

Tags: c#, stopwatch

Here is my code when click a button in C# WinForm:

```
private void aesactive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Reset();
        stopWatch.Start();
        string original = textBox4.Text;
        using (var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            string inputkey = textBox5.Text;
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputkey);
            random.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, key);

        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        textBox6.Text = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms ";

    }
```

But when I click that button twice, or more, the results always 0 ms. Can anybody explain to me the reasons ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Everytime you click the button the code creates a new StopWatch

Comment: make the Stopwatch a part of the class. not the method.

Comment: It's possible that your operation is faster than the resolution of the Stopwatch

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to accumulate time, move `Stopwatch` variable outside the method, and remove the call to `Reset()`:

```
private readonly Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
private void aesactive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    stopWatch.Start();
    ...
    stopWatch.Stop();
    textBox6.Text = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms ";
}
```

Now that adding time is a "one-way street," consider adding a button to reset the stopwatch:

```
private void aesreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    stopWatch.Reset();
}
```

**Note:** Modern CPUs are capable of running millions instructions per millisecond, so it may require you to click the button many times for the value in `textBox6` to move off zero.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that solution. Last night, I tried to move Stopwatch variable outside but still keeping the Reset() in the method. Nothing changed. Maybe a reset button is needed :D